# problems using the Split Features tool

Tags: polygon, splitting

i'm using the split features tool to create two polygons from a bigger one. The problem is, when i save the split i have done, half of the polygon disappears. But sometimes, after doing some more polygons they appear again, and the last ones in with i was working disappear.
 Do you know what is happening and what is the solution?

PS: This Shape was made by other people and i don't know how it was made, neither in which program has been  created.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using?

Comment: i'm using Qgis 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the geometry with the check geometry tool and rebuild the spatial index.

Comment: i've done that and don't have any problem